# replacing a positioned value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
    A  B  C 
0   s  d  f
1   3  5  3 
2   4  4  5
3   6  6  6
```

I would like to replace the value at `df.iloc[[0],[0]]` from `s` to `j` . How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass positional indexers to `iat`:

```
df.iat[0, 0] = 'j'
```

Or, pass labels to `at`:

```
df.at[0, 'A'] = 'j'
```

```
df

   A  B  C
0  j  d  f
1  3  5  3
2  4  4  5
3  6  6  6
```

Comment: Didnt knew about `iat` existence , very useful!! Thank you!